# Mysql ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry. Update rows that won't violate an unique constraint

Tags: mysql, sql-update, constraints

I have the following table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `user_favourite_posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_post_unique` (`user_id`,`post_id`))
```

I am trying to update all the rows with post_id in (1000, 1001) to post_id = 1005, something like the following:

```
update user_posts set post_id=1005 where post_id in(1000, 1001);
```

But I am getting the following error because of the user_post_unique constraint:

> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 1005 for key 'user_post_unique'

Good. This is working as expected.

But I would like to update all the rows that won't violate the constraint. Is it possible in one single sentence? I can't figure out how to do it without removing some mysql flags or using temporary tables as I cannot use the same table in a subquery.

UPDATE:

An example, having the following data

```
+-------+---------+---------+
| id    | user_id | post_id |
+-------+---------+---------+
|  4581 |       2 | 1001    |
|  9739 |       2 | 1005    |
|  7324 |       3 | 1001    |
+-------+---------+---------+
```

I would like to update all the rows without problems, so the one with `id 4581` remain the same

Comment: Uh, you can't do this.  That is why you have a unique constraint on the table, to prevent patterns that you don't want to occur.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I am editing now the question because what I really want is to update those rows with users that don't have the relation yet. In case of duplicating I just will remove one of them.

Comment: That sounds wrong. Gordon's right: the constraint is doing its job here, preventing you from breaking things on a whim. You need to think about your requirement more carefully.

Comment: I realized my answer was incorrect for the case. It looks like it wont work because of the unique constraint you have and another row already matches the criteria so it's marking it as a duplicate as it should

Comment: I don't, they are not my requirements :) There is really no way to do something like that? Even not updating the conflicted rows, just the rest of them. Editing now.

Comment: Do you need to update existing rows, or is it okay to delete them and add other rows, with the "correct" post_id, and a new id?

Comment: I can do that, of course. But this is the kind of stuff I would like to avoid. Just only for using a cleaner solution, if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
update user_posts a
    left join user_posts b ON b.post_id IN (1000,1001,1005) AND b.user_id = a.user_id AND b.post_id > a.post_id
set a.post_id = 1005 
where 
    a.post_id in (1000, 1001)
AND b.id IS NULL
;
```

Comment: That's not the only possible unique violation. If a user has a post_id = 1000 and a post_id= 1001, it will try to write 2 lines with post_id = 1005 and the same user

Comment: @JeanDoux you are right. I modified the join condition to reflect this additional scenario. I think it should now update only one of the potential 2 records with 1000 or 1001 for post_id

Comment: Why `b.id is null`?

Comment: @y2josei because if it's not, it means there will be 2nd row matching your unique key after the update.

Comment: Oh I see the `left` now. It looks promising! I will let you know in a while.